# Yarn 2 root binaries unavailable in all workspaces

Tags: yarnpkg-v2

I've upgrade Yarn and now no workspace script such as `yarn test` will run without installing say `jest` in each workspace, or calling it with `run -T jest`. I am not finding much in the docs to support that installing binaries in workspace root is pointless which makes me wonder if something is corrupt. I am reluctant to specify the full `node_modules/.bin` path.

My yarnrc:

```
nodeLinker: node-modules

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs
```

To clarify further - in my root I installed say `jest` and can run `yarn test` from root. But navigating to a workspace then running any of my scripts in that package.json such as

```
"test":"jest"
```

Will yield an error about jest not found.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a discussion on this https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/discussions/2825

Evidently it's a mess. The choices are:

- install same package in each workspace
- prepend `yarn -T` to every binary command in all scripts
- don't run scripts from a workspace, instead fill the root package.json with all your 100's of custom per workspace scripts.
- use npm